# Apache server is crashing while trying to execute Java

Tags: java, python, apache, ubuntu, jvm

This is the error report:

```
[Sat Jan 21 12:07:50.518064 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 8928:tid 139985251233280] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Jan 21 12:07:51.400192 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 9240:tid 139692690144768] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.11.
[Sat Jan 21 12:07:51.400309 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 9240:tid 139692690144768] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.12+.
[Sat Jan 21 12:07:51.405286 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 9240:tid 139692690144768] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.12+ configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jan 21 12:07:51.405340 2017] [core:notice] [pid 9240:tid 139692690144768] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.453647 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] Invoked on Sat Jan 21 12:07:57 UTC 2017 with arguments: -loadClassifier /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/StanFordNer/stanford-ner-2016-10-31/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz -textFile /tmp/tmpb53bnN -outputFormat slashTags -tokenizerFactory edu.stanford.nlp.process.WhitespaceTokenizer -tokenizerOptions "tokenizeNLs=false" -encoding utf8
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.454348 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] tokenizerFactory=edu.stanford.nlp.process.WhitespaceTokenizer
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.454365 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] tokenizerOptions="tokenizeNLs=false"
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.454381 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] loadClassifier=/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/StanFordNer/stanford-ner-2016-10-31/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.454388 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] encoding=utf8
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.454392 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] textFile=/tmp/tmpb53bnN
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.454397 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] outputFormat=slashTags
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.454415 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] 
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472037 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001] [2017-01-21 12:08:02,461] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472087 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472093 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472099 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472104 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472109 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472113 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472118 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472122 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472126 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001]     rv = self.dispatch_request()
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472131 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472135 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001]     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472140 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 34, in homepage
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472163 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001]     NERtagger.tag(testy.split())
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472169 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tag/stanford.py", line 71, in tag
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472173 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001]     return sum(self.tag_sents([tokens]), [])
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472177 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tag/stanford.py", line 94, in tag_sents
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472182 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001]     stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472186 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 134, in java
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472190 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001]     raise OSError('Java command failed : ' + str(cmd))
[Sat Jan 21 12:08:02.472195 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 9245:tid 139692552484608] [client 141.69.97.198:10001] OSError: Java command failed : [u'/usr/bin/java', '-mx1000m', '-cp', '/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/StanFordNer/stanford-ner-2016-10-31/stanford-ner.jar:/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/StanFordNer/stanford-ner-2016-10-31/stanford-ner-3.7.0-javadoc.jar:/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/StanFordNer/stanford-ner-2016-10-31/stanford-ner-3.7.0-sources.jar:/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/StanFordNer/stanford-ner-2016-10-31/stanford-ner-3.7.0.jar:/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/StanFordNer/stanford-ner-2016-10-31/lib/jollyday-0.4.9.jar:/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/StanFordNer/stanford-ner-2016-10-31/lib/joda-time.jar:/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/StanFordNer/stanford-ner-2016-10-31/lib/stanford-ner-resources.jar', 'edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier', '-loadClassifier', '/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/StanFordNer/stanford-ner-2016-10-31/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz', '-textFile', '/tmp/tmpb53bnN', '-outputFormat', 'slashTags', '-tokenizerFactory', 'edu.stanford.nlp.process.WhitespaceTokenizer', '-tokenizerOptions', '"tokenizeNLs=false"', '-encoding', 'utf8']
```

Server Configuration:
512 MB Memory / 20 GB Disk / NYC3 - Ubuntu 16.10 x64

I think the problem is occurring because the JVM cant't run the file with only 512 mb memory. The problem occurs when I try to execute from my apache server (both Java and Python is installed in it):

```
 testy = request.args.get('query')
  path_to_model = "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/StanFordNer/stanford-ner-2016-10-31/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz"
  path_to_jar = "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/StanFordNer/stanford-ner-2016-10-31/stanford-ner.jar"
  NERtagger = StanfordNERTagger(path_to_model, path_to_jar)
  tagging=NERtagger.tag(testy.split())
```

english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz is a big file which size is 38 mb. This code runs perfectly in my laptop which has i7/16 gb ram. But is not running on my online server which has only 512 mb ram. The code runs in my server if I try with my custom small size ner-customModel.ser.gz which size is 48 kb.

```
 testy = request.args.get('query')
  path_to_model = "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/StanFordNer/stanford-ner-2016-10-31/custom/ner-customModel.ser.gz"
  path_to_jar = "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/StanFordNer/stanford-ner-2016-10-31/stanford-ner.jar"
  NERtagger = StanfordNERTagger(path_to_model, path_to_jar)
  tagging=NERtagger.tag(testy.split())
```

I think the problem is not with Stanford library because both code is working fine in my laptop python installation and the later code is also running in my server. Its producing the error only when I try to execute the large ser stanford-ner-2016-10-31.ser.gz which is 38 MB. I think in that case JVM try to use more ram. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: so stanford is using java? Starting java out of python sounds like a strange thing to do..

Comment: anyway: can you post the output of [this command](https://gist.github.com/philippkeller/b75512054e0e5e67dd1b6e520c4194e1)? This is taken from your error log. This is where apache stumbles and if it was "out of memory" then the output of this command should show

Comment: I am using DigitalOcean cloud and the nano terminal doesn't allow me to paste this code in the terminal. I tried to write but the line itself is very large. I solved the problem by creating a swap file. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Stanford developed this NER with Java with the target language java. But it has interface to use with python.

Comment: can you post your solution as an answer below to help other people who run into the same problem?